# Xamarin Android - Startup Crash

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me fix the following issue which is occurring:

**Startup crash**
This problem does only occur when in Release mode and when the "Use Shared Runtime" checkbox is unchecked. Sadly enough archiving (and thus distributing) the app forces you to uncheck this option.

Since i've never developed apps by using Xamarin, i'm clueless about what to do. This app is developed several years ago by someone who has left the company long ago.

Running the app locally by using the debug configuration, everything works fine. But when i switch to the release configurations the app crashes with the following output:

```
02-13 15:04:54.847 E/art     ( 6038): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0xec9d54d5 (index 21813 in a table of size 66)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0xec9d54d5
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from void mono.android.Runtime.init(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x762de280 self=0xece05400
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | sysTid=6038 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf00f2534
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | state=R schedstat=( 386098851 11374041 344 ) utm=20 stm=18 core=4 HZ=100
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | stack=0xff5fa000-0xff5fc000 stackSize=8MB
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #00 pc 0034ecc5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #01 pc 0032f481  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+308)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #02 pc 00238765  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+848)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #03 pc 00238cfb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #04 pc 00332ea9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+240)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #05 pc 000c9b61  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+120)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #06 pc 000c9113  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+190)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #07 pc 000ca14b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+186)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #08 pc 000c90c1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+108)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #09 pc 000c854b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+802)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #10 pc 000cc6f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+114)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #11 pc 000cbd25  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+512)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #12 pc 000c1507  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI16CallObjectMethodEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+50)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #13 pc 000063c0   (???)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at mono.android.Runtime.init(Native method)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:49)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:22)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java:-1)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] 
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Runtime aborting...
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Aborting thread:
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x762de280 self=0xece05400
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=6038 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf00f2534
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=R schedstat=( 406851471 11806888 420 ) utm=21 stm=18 core=4 HZ=100
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xff5fa000-0xff5fc000 stackSize=8MB
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 0034ecc5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 0032f481  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+308)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 003224f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+24)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #03 pc 00322381  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+424)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #04 pc 0031911b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+90)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 000b4ac1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+864)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 00238a95  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1664)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #07 pc 00238cfb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #08 pc 00332ea9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+240)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #09 pc 000c9b61  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+120)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #10 pc 000c9113  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+190)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #11 pc 000ca14b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+186)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #12 pc 000c90c1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+108)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #13 pc 000c854b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+802)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #14 pc 000cc6f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+114)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #15 pc 000cbd25  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+512)
02-13 15:04:54.954 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #16 pc 000c1507  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI16CallObjectMethodEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+50)
```

Got any clue?

I couldn't paste the whole stacktrace since stackoverflow only allows me to enter 30.000 characters. I'll post more if needed.

Cheers

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I read "MultiDex support library is disabled.", could you try enabling it and/or creating a class that extends Application?

Comment: Multidex was enabled, disabling gave me the following output:  

`code
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0xec9d54d5 (index 21813 in a table of size 66)

02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0xec9d54d5  

02-13 15:04:54.900 F/art     ( 6038): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from void mono.android.Runtime.init(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)`

Comment: See my answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508242/how-to-debug-jni-detected-error-in-application-use-of-invalid-jobject/40512128#40512128

Comment: I will look into this, I'll let you know if it worked.