# What is the correct moment to call Dispose() when using the ViewHolder pattern?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, dispose

I use the ViewHolder pattern as described by James Montemagno

https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

Considering the objects called by FindViewById, when should I call dispose? What is safe and correct to do. I should do it at some moment:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/

> To shorten object lifetime, Java.Lang.Object.Dispose() should be invoked. TThis will manually "sever" the connection on the object between the
>   two VMs by freeing the global reference, thus allowing the objects to
>   be collected faster.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are relegated to `ListView`?  Please consider using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: The real Recyclerview requires a more recent android version if I prefer to use it without (support) libraries or other additional dependecies.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` is pretty old(Android 1.0). It was tightly coupled and not built with performance in mind. Lots of hacks were needed to keep it relevant. `RecyclerView` fills that gap.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqBlYJTfLP4

As for when you should call `Dispose()`, `RecyclerView` should handle this basic functionality via the `LayoutManager`. On the `ViewHolder` side, you can follow a basic `Dispose` pattern:

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose (disposing);
        if(ItemView != null)
        {
            ItemView.Click -= HandleClick;
        }
        _listener = null; //Listener might just be a simple Action<int> like in this example: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/RecyclerViewer/MainActivity.cs#L111
    }
```

In which you only care about Disposing the base and any Event Handlers you set up. However if your `RecyclerView` uses a bit of images in the `View` it's inflating, you will want to ensure you properly manage those resources as the Android GC will not be able to collect these items as they will be referenced by Xamarin.Android's GC(And they will be a small reference like a few bytes worth). Somehow you have to sever the link between the two GCs so it can be eligible for collection. You can read more about the GC Algorithm here: [Xamarin Android garbage collection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066640/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-algorithm/39083399#39083399) and the cause here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#Use_Weak_References_to_Prevent_Immortal_Objects

To do that, we can sever the relationship via a couple ways:

1. `MyObject = null;`
2. `MyObject.Dispose();`

Either way should mark these items eligible for GC. In the case of `Drawable` you may also want to set the respective `ImageView` or object that the `Drawable` is being set in to `null` such as `SetBackgroundDrawable`/etc.

TLDR; Use `RecyclerView`, and remember to manage any `Bitmap/Drawable` resources appropriately.

Comment: For drawables which you don't need anymore 1. get the Bitmap of the Imageview Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.Drawable).Bitmap  2. Set Drawable to null - iv.SetImageBitmap(null); 3. call Recycle method of Bitmap - bm.Recycle(); .. Already had the problem that Bitmaps were hold too long in the heap.