# How to handle touch events on a view after it has been disposed

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

SO I have this basic Xamarin Android Application where the Home Activity houses a couple of fragments. Each fragment as usual housing a hierarchy of views. 
The Application has a auto logout feature (once the user logs in) by which if device left idle for a certain period of time is logged out. After an auto logout, when the user opens the app and logs in, the last fragment (when user left the app) is shown.

I am facing a random crash at this stage where it looks like the views has been disposed or garbage collected but the Application still has reference to the old fragments. The stack trace looks something like -

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime: Process: PinForce.Mobile, PID: 3292

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 1 more

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type PinForce.Framework.Survey.Display.SearchFormView from native handle 0xffc7616c (key_handle 0x391202b). ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for PinForce.Framework.Survey.Display.SearchFormView::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00058] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00138] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x001b0] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x000e5] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.Object._GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x0001a] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00006] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x00000] in <64fedfa134eb440aa45b8be4ef49a962>:0 

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:3cb395be-06f7-4df6-8dc1-7552ee0d6361 (intptr,intptr,intptr)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at md5c50fdf4dafbb5388e2f5304a2b7613f8.SearchFormView.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at md5c50fdf4dafbb5388e2f5304a2b7613f8.SearchFormView.dispatchTouchEvent(SearchFormView.java:54)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.cancelTouchTarget(ViewGroup.java:2717)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4943)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4923)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4854)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1270)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1552)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:487)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)

01-05 13:58:51.941  3292  3292 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
```

I read up a little bit and it looks like a case of premature dispose. I should mention that most of my views implement the dispose pattern and releases any memory. 
My question is how do i handle this ? Should I implement the special (`IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership) constructor` ? This special constructor i guess might prevent the crash but will it be useful in my scenario ?

Note : I am trying to figure out steps as to why my views are getting disposed prematurely. I guess fixing that should solve my problem but till then need a placeholder solution. Already spent couple of days on this.

**Edit** -

```
public override void OnDestroyView()
{
    if (_ssv != null)
    {
        _ssv.Dispose();
        _ssv = null;
    }
    base.OnDestroyView();
}
```

Above method is in one of my fragment. On view destroy, Am trying to dispose all the views manually. Please note that in native Android we generally do not do anything like this as the framework take care of relasing any view references when the container Activity or fragment is being destroyed. But we were working on this Application from pretty early versions of Xamarin which were unstable and had many memory related issues. So to avoid them, all our views has the dispose pattern implemented and is called when the activity or fragment is destroyed. Now the question is should i defer this a bit later may be to `onDestroy()` of the fragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066640/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-algorithm

Comment: @SushiHangover I understand the basic memory management in Xamarin. But the parts related to Peer object disposal and Java activation are a bit confusing and not well documented

Comment: My question was if a view gets disposed prematurely for some reason, is it  OK to provide the special constructor for that view, so that ACW can create an instance of it when required (after it was disposed) ? My guess was that might solve the crash (see the stack trace) but might not initialize my view in the proper state. My question was how to sanely handle such scenarios (i.e have no crash) where there is out of sync disposal between peer objects ?

Comment: Can you have a look at the stacktrace posted in the question. This was a case where `Java.Lang.Object.Dispose() ` was called on an object resulting in freeing the global reference in the managed code . But Java code somehow still referred to it resulting in the above crash. Section from Xamarin doc - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture#Premature_Dispose()_Calls

Comment: `Each Java.lang.Object-based class in your app get a ACW-based Java generated class that also includes an IntPtr to the C# class` - Where is this mentioned. From what i read, only the Managed code has a gobla handle (or inputPtr).

Comment: Can you post your `SearchFormView` class (just the constructors, any registration attributes on that class, etc.., no display methods, etc are needed)

Comment: Sorry, technically not an C# `IntPtr`, but an `java.lang.Object`. The ACW Java code implements `mono.android.IGCUserPeer` and performs a `mono.android.TypeManager.Activate`.  The internal reference array of `java.lang.Object`s are added via the `monodroidAddReference` method within the ACW.

Comment: I edited my question to add a snapshot of the code.

Comment: I have seen this type of crash on Android apps happening usually when you leave events subscribed in an ActivivityFragment/View. Follow the rule: Subscribe on Create, Unsubscribe on Pause in the view that is giving you problems to see if that helps

Comment: @apineda for registering events or broadcasts, what you said works and infact is what should be done. What I am doing here is destroying the view and i guess doing it on `onPause` is not a good idea as the Activity or Container is still around.

Comment: @Dibzmania no, I don't say to destroy your views on the OnPause, but do not get why you are infact destroying it. I mentioned the events because I have seen issues when working with Fragments on Xamarin.Android.

A common error I have seen is something like 
`var frg = new MyFragment();` 
then navigate back or move to another Fragment and then create another instance of the same fragment. That first fragment created keeps there in memory holding events subscriptions which eventually makes the app crashing.

Comment: @apineda As i mentioned, explicit view destroy is done to avoid possible memory leaks.

Comment: @Dibzmania understand your point but I wouldn't suggestion to dispose the Views that represent your Fragments on the OnDestroyView as the Fragment could be recreated from that point and you would need to recreate all your views (OnCreateView) again. I will put the cleaning a little bit down in the Fragment Life Cycle (OnDestroy or lower if possible).

Android Fragments Lifecycle events:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @apineda I agree to that. Unfortunately that would mean a lot of code changes for me at this stage.