# Understanding activity allocations in the Xamarin profiler

Tags: android, xamarin, memory, xamarin.android, memory-profiling

I'm trying to understand how to read the data I get in the Xamarin Android profiler. I was stepping through our app and found out that all activities that get loaded over and over from stepping through the app, regardless of whether they are kept on the history stack or not, are kept in memory. For example, I have an "About" activity, I set it to have no history in the backstack, and I opened and closed it 8 times, the profiler is telling me sure enough, that I have 8 about activity objects allocated, it stands to reason then that this would be a problem, because I would assume activities are garbage collector roots, and if they don't get cleaned up, objects that they reference wouldn't get cleaned up either, my allocated memory reflects this theory as each time I close and reopen the activities, my memory grows and grows and grows.

All this leads me to my question, am I misunderstanding the data I'm reading or is this accurate? I wouldn't assume that the app doesn't clean up activities when they close out, but I could be missing something...I guess I just need someone to explain this to me, because to be frank, the documentation on the profiler is really not up to scratch.

Comment: I have an answer that might help explain the general process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066640/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-algorithm I believe what you are seeing is the GC not "working" because it only will run when the minor heap has run out of memory for new allocations. If you force a GC, you should see cleanup if there are no outstanding handles being referenced (i.e. their relationships and children have been severed by setting to `null` or calling `Dispose()`)

Comment: Great answer, much appreciated!