# Who and when should dispose an intent?

Tags: android, xamarin, idisposable

I noticed that Xamarin `Intent` is `IDisposable` so now I wonder what is proper way to dispose it. Let's say I create it and send it, in some activity I receive it and... is it OK to dispose it right away?

I am asking what is the proper (as guideline) way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The objects in Xamarin.Android that inherit `Java.Lang.Object` also follow the `IDisposable` pattern to ensure a proper 1:1 mapping between the Mono GC and the Android GC(Managed and Native GC respectfully). They have a representation of an object in both VMs that has a concept of a bridge to communicate when to collect them.

They are known as **Peer Objects** that are normally collected by the GC.

Calling `Dispose()` is optional because one of the GCs will take care of it. You can however shorten the object's lifetime by invoking `Dispose()` to sever the reference which allows a GC to collect it earlier.

You can read more about this in the following places:

[Xamarin Android garbage collection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066640/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-algorithm)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/garbage-collection